# I'm drawing images in visual basic using a loop but only the most recent image is visible

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

First - Some background.

I'm building a pizza ordering app (school assignment) which lets you choose your toppings and then draws those toppings on a pizza when you check a box. I have an array of different pepperoni pictures and when the checkbox is selected I'm randomly drawing 38 pepperonis within the radius of the pizza. (I may have to fine tune this later). I've got it working... but when I draw - Only the last pepperoni is visible. Here's my code:

```
Public Class ToppingsPage
Private Img1 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Desktop\Visual Studio School Files\Pizza Images\Toppings\P-1.png")
Private handTossed As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\hand tossed.png")
Private handMade As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\deepdish in pan.png")
Private thinCrust As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\thin.png")
Private brooklynStyle As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\brooklyn style.png")

Private pepperoniOne As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\Toppings\P-1.png")
Private pepperoniTwo As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\Toppings\P-2.png")
Private pepperoniThree As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\dunnage\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pizzaTest\Images\Toppings\P-3.png")

Private pTopping As Boolean = False


Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    If Form1.pizzaType = 1 Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(handTossed, 360, 10)
    End If
    If Form1.pizzaType = 2 Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(handMade, 360, 10)
    End If
    If Form1.pizzaType = 3 Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(thinCrust, 360, 10)
    End If
    If Form1.pizzaType = 4 Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(brooklynStyle, 360, 10)
    End If
    If pTopping = True Then
        Dim counter = 0
        Dim imgPic(3) As Image
        imgPic(0) = pepperoniOne
        imgPic(1) = pepperoniTwo
        imgPic(2) = pepperoniThree
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((2 * Rnd()) + 0))
        Dim xCoord As Integer = CInt(Int((500 * Rnd()) + 370))
        Dim yCoord As Integer = CInt(Int((300 * Rnd()) + 20))
        Do Until counter > 38
            Dim i = imgPic(value)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, xCoord, yCoord)
            counter += 1
        Loop
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    pTopping = True
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhh I think i got it. I'm creating my random x,y coordinates outside the loop so the image is being redrawn in the same location over and over and over.

Here's the right code:

```
If pTopping = True Then
        Dim counter = 0
        Dim imgPic(3) As Image
        imgPic(0) = pepperoniOne
        imgPic(1) = pepperoniTwo
        imgPic(2) = pepperoniThree
        Do Until counter > 38
            Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((2 * Rnd()) + 0))
            Dim i = imgPic(value)
            Dim xCoord As Integer = CInt(Int((500 * Rnd()) + 370))
            Dim yCoord As Integer = CInt(Int((300 * Rnd()) + 20))
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, xCoord, yCoord)
            counter += 1
        Loop
    End If
```

And here's a picture of the results...
[image]
I've got a little fine tuning to do.

Okay... So I'm working the polar coordinate angle (pun intended) and I've got it working but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to move the origin. Here's my code:

```
Public Class polarAndCartesian

Property X As Double
    Property Y As Double
    Sub New(Radius As Double, AngleDegree As Double)
        Dim AngleRadian As Double = AngleDegree * 2 * Math.PI / 360
        X = Radius * Math.Cos(AngleRadian)
        Y = Radius * Math.Sin(AngleRadian)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CartesianToPolar
    Property Radius As Double
    Property AngleRadian As Double
    ReadOnly Property AngleDegree As Double
        Get
            Return AngleRadian * 360 / (2 * Math.PI)
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New(X As Double, Y As Double)
        Radius = (X ^ 2 + Y ^ 2) ^ 0.5
        AngleRadian = Math.Atan2(Y, X)
    End Sub


End Class
```

And this is how I'm drawing them:

```
    If pTopping = True Then
        Dim counter = 0
        Dim imgPic(3) As Image
        imgPic(0) = pepperoniOne
        imgPic(1) = pepperoniTwo
        imgPic(2) = pepperoniThree
        Do Until counter > 38
            Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((3 * Rnd()) + 0))
            Dim i = imgPic(value)
            Dim PTC As New polarAndCartesian(CInt(Int((60 * Rnd()) + 0)), CInt(Int((360 * Rnd()) + 0)))
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, CInt(PTC.X), CInt(PTC.Y))
            counter += 1
        Loop
    End If
```

And this is the end result:
[image]

Comment: A slight bug: be careful with your `value` variable. It will only select between `imgPic(0)` and `imgPic(1)`.

Comment: It's possibly easier to select a random location on the pizza by generating a random [Polar coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (r, θ) and converting it to Cartesian.

Comment: Didn't know that was available.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking into this now... I'll let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it, Polar Coordinates are really the ONLY way to go without dropping toppings half on your crust and half off.